# selectElement.value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develop a system for solving rubik cube using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery.

You can view it at:
[rubik fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shubhamkundu/ytcek085/)

The problem is in the below function:

```
function processFile(e) {
    var selects;
    var file = e.target.result,
    results;
    if (file && file.length) {
        var i, j, lines = file.split("\n");
        selects = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("select");
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                selects[i*9+j].value = lines[i].split(" ")[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we change the below line

```
selects[i*9+j].value = lines[i].split(" ")[j];
```

to

```
selects[i*9+j].style.backgroundColor = lines[i].split(" ")[j];
```

then it is working fine, but I need the value to be changed, not the background color.

Here is one of the select elements:

```
<select class="cell 00">
    <option class="colorOption" value="white" title="white" style="background-color: white;"></option>
    <option class="colorOption" value="red" title="red" style="background-color: red;"></option>
    <option class="colorOption" value="blue" title="blue" style="background-color: blue;"></option>
    <option class="colorOption" value="orange" title="orange" style="background-color: orange;"></option>
    <option class="colorOption" value="green" title="green" style="background-color: green;"></option>
    <option class="colorOption" value="yellow" title="yellow" style="background-color: yellow;"></option>
</select>
```

Here is a sample value for lines:

```
lines = "yellow white white white red white white white white white white white white blue white white white white white white white white orange white white white white white white white white green white white white white white white white white white white green white white orange white white white yellow white white white white ";
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update**: The problem is now solved.

I just had to trigger the change (except the middle select : j != 4)
by adding the following lines:

```
if (j != 4) {
    $(selects[i*9+j]).trigger('change');
}
```

So the changed js function is as follows:

```
function processFile(e) {
    var selects;
    var file = e.target.result,
        results;
    if (file && file.length) {
        var i, j, lines = file.split("\n"), colors;
        selects = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("select");
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                selects[i*9+j].value = lines[i].split(" ")[j];
                if (j != 4) {                            //added this lines
                    $(selects[i*9+j]).trigger('change'); //added this lines
                }                                        //added this lines
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: jquery for which part?

Comment: created select elements and options through jQuery, please check : https://jsfiddle.net/shubhamkundu/ytcek085/1/

Comment: `.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("select");`??? aren't you getting errors? If so what are they?

Comment: No error for that as style.backgroundColor is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice piece of code. But there is one issue - you're mixing jQuery with JS, so - you may be expecting select to behave the same after setting value, as it behaves after licking option. It's not gonna happen, as it's the JQ "change" listener that is changing select color. 
So, we got 2 ways - to set both backgroundColor & value inside loop (wich is perfectly valid, maybe not fully DRY), or to go full JQ with changing values, and let the "change" listener do its work. The second approach could look like this:
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/dpnLjhd5/7/)

```
function processFile(e) {
    var selects;
    var file = e.target.result,
        results;
    if (file && file.length) {
        var i, j, lines = file.split("\n"), colors;
        selects = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("select");
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        console.log('cc',selects[i*9+j],selects[i*9+j].value,lines[i].split(" ")[j])
        var newVal = lines[i].split(" ")[j]
                var opt = selects[i*9+j].querySelector('[title="'+newVal+'"]');
        if (opt) {
          $(selects[i*9+j]).val(lines[i].split(" ")[j])
            $(selects[i*9+j]).trigger('change');
        }
        else {
            selects[i*9+j].value = newVal
          selects[i*9+j].style.backgroundColor = newVal
        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

s you can see, there's one another catch - middle select don't have options, so there's nothing else to do but set this by hand.

Comment: I know about the middle select, if no value matches, it should select a blank value, which will create no problem for me

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and help, the golden line is :"$(selects[i*9+j]).trigger('change');"; It is giving me the expected results

Comment: also I need to check one more thing, if (j != 4), then only I should trigger, otherwise it's not working

Comment: Yup, that what's I'm talking about, and that's why I'm checking for "opt" in my code - to handle this middle select with j = 4 :) But watch out for its values, as I see that setting values of empty select might not work at all (just backgroundColor works for them). So, I would consider putting there only 1 option - option with given color :)

Comment: Ok, but setting value also works, a blank value is selected, what is not working is the trigger